# delete directories step by step without calculate the whole amount before

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesystems

I have a lan hard disk, on which are millions of files i will delete. But everytime I call the delete function (Windows-Explorer or rmdir) the system calculates to death before any file will be deleted. So i'm searching for an automated way to delete files and directories iterativley ad hoc.

Comment: If what you have posted below is not an answer then please delete it after copying its content as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48240062/edit) to your question. If it is, then please be clear that it is in order to remove any confusion.

Comment: Try `rd C:\folder /s`.

Comment: The below post is an answer. I can as soon tomorrow set it to accepted answer. 
As I wrote in the first post, I've tried to user single batch command `rmdir`. But this will first calculate the whole amount of what ot delete - and this process tooked hours before anything was deleted, so I cancelded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created me a batch file that handles me the above features. So I can start the script an it will erase files ad hoc. Even if I have to pause I can abort the script and continue at a later time with the processing at the point I cancelled the script before:

```
@echo off
set OFFSETDIR="%1"
if "%OFFSETDIR%"=="" goto HELP
pushd %OFFSETDIR%
cd /d %OFFSETDIR%
set OFFSETDIR="%cd%"

:PSUBDIR
for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('DIR /A:D /b') do (
pushd "%%~fD"
goto PSUBDIR
)
echo [INFO] erase /F /Q "%cd%\*"
erase /F /Q "%cd%\*"
if errorlevel 1 goto ANYERROR
if "%cd%"==%OFFSETDIR% goto PEND
set LASTSUBDIR="%cd%"
popd
echo [INFO] rmdir /q %LASTSUBDIR%
rmdir /q %LASTSUBDIR%||rem
if errorlevel 1 goto ERASEHIDDEN
goto PSUBDIR

:ERASEHIDDEN
echo [WARNING] there was an error when trying to rmdir %LASTSUBDIR%
echo [WARNING] this may be in cause of existing hidden files in the directory. so...
echo [INFO] erase /F /Q /A:H %LASTSUBDIR%\*
erase /F /Q /A:H %LASTSUBDIR%\*
if errorlevel 1 goto ANYERROR
echo [INFO] hidden files erased successfully. second try for rmdir %LASTSUBDIR%
rmdir /q %LASTSUBDIR%||rem
if errorlevel 1 goto ANYERROR
goto PSUBDIR

:ANYERROR
echo [ERROR] the script has cancelled due to an unhandled error
popd
goto SEND

:PEND
echo [INFO] the script has successfull ended
popd
goto SEND

:HELP
echo [INFO] A little script to erase iterative recursivley files and directories.
echo [INFO] Usage: %0 PATH_TO_DELETE
echo [INFO] the script will delete all files an directories below the given path.
echo [INFO]
echo [INFO] directories will be erased with rmdir /q
echo [INFO] /q supresses the user-confirmation
echo [INFO] files will be erased with erase /f /q
echo [INFO] /f means to delete also readonly-files
echo [INFO] /q supresses the user-confirmation
echo [INFO] when the rmdir will fail, there's a second try to erase also hidden files
echo [INFO] with option /a:h

:SEND
echo.
```